# Finding the Parent of the this Pointer on Debug

Tags: visual-c++, oop

In VC++, how to find the parent or the Class which it belongs to on the Debug mode using the Watch Window?

Comment: Are you talking about what the "this" points to?

Comment: what do you mean by the "parent of a pointer". Do you mean the dynamic type of the referenced object ?

Comment: For a class, it can have one or more super classes and those have the virual and non virtual functions. In such case, on debug the this pointer under execution may span in those functions. For this I am unable to find the 'real parent' of the this pointer.